# Predicting Future survival rate in R using Survival Analysis

Tags: r, prediction, survival

I have only 1 month of day to day survival rate data on a plant subject. I want to be able to use this data to predict the survival rate for all the future months. Is there any way that I can do that in r using existing function? Basically, I have something like surv(time, death)~1. I have no other variables that I want to use, I just want to calculate the survival rate for the future months that I do not have data for. Thank you so much.

Comment: This question is basically a request to teach you about survival analysis. It belongs on CrossValidated.com. The fact that you want to use R does not make it a coding question ... yet. Come back when you have some data as an example and can tell us what kind of analysis to do.

Comment: @DavidZhen:  Now that this is in the correct venue, you should search in this section with terms "survival forecast".